# Why is Adaptation-Differences tag being removed from my question?

Tags: discussion, tags

My question [How closely tied into the source material is Assassin's Creed?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/66640/how-closely-tied-into-the-source-material-is-assassins-creed) is specifically about the differences between the source material and the movie adaption.

So why is the tag being removed multiple times? https://movies.stackexchange.com/revisions/66640/5

***The tag was used in the same context of every other question tagged with it, before it was unilaterally changed by the two answerers here, changing its usage by the community... Interesting.***

```
 8
 votes

 1
 answer

 301
 views
 Why are two Jungle book movies being made consecutively?
 production the-jungle-book-2016 adaptation-differences jungle-book-origins modified just now Catija 18.5k
 6
 votes

 1
 answer

 112
 views
 Why Did Milos Forman Change 'Hair' as Much as He Did?
 play-adaptation hair modified 23 secs ago Napoleon Wilson♦ 32.6k
 4
 votes

 0
 answers

 66
 views
 Why Did Tim Burton cut the Ballad from Sweeney Todd?
 musical play-adaptation sweeney-todd modified 41 secs ago Napoleon Wilson♦ 32.6k

 5
 votes

 0
 answers

 34
 views
 What changes were made in Princess Kaguya from the original Tale of the Bamboo Cutter story?
 book-adaptation tale-of-princess-kaguya modified 7 mins ago Catija 18.5k
 2
 votes

 0
 answers

 144
 views
 Glengarry Glen Ross - Willamson left the office before Roma got the Lingk contract
 plot-explanation chronology glengarry-glen-ross play-adaptation modified 8 mins ago Catija 18.5k
 4
 votes

 0
 answers

 64
 views
 Why Did Tim Burton cut the Ballad from Sweeney Todd?
 musical adaptation sweeney-todd play-adaptation modified 13 mins ago Catija 18.5k
 6
 votes

 1
 answer

 111
 views
 Why Did Milos Forman Change 'Hair' as Much as He Did?
 adaptation hair play-adaptation modified 13 mins ago Catija 18.5k
 7
 votes

 0
 answers

 65
 views
 How accurate an adaptation was “Behind the Candelabra”?
 book-adaptation behind-the-candelabra modified 16 mins ago Catija 18.5k
```

Answer (score 5):

The tag was originally created *not* to discuss the difference of an adaptation to its source material (which your question seems to do), but for discussing the **differences of two adapations *between each other***. Compare for this the comment on [the question that introduced it](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/18929/49):

> Is the new tag adaptation-differences really necessary, wouldn't comic-adaptation already do? (just a question)
>
> That'd be the wrong tag as we're comparing two sets of movies, not a comic to its movie adaptation.

So it doesn't seem relevant on the question you're talking about, as also explained in the edit comment of the corresponding revision.

---

**However**, from looking at the questions that bear the tag, it seems it is rarely ever used for that purpose and **people seem confused about what it should actually be used for**.  I see that it is quite much to require users being aware of such intricacies, especially since the tag lacks any tag wiki with usage guidelines.

Seeing how most of the questions it's on are just discussing an adapation and its difference to the source material, those cases are actually handled by the `...-adaptation` tags perfectly well already and would need their tags to be cleaned up anyway. And since the rare questions that actually compare two different adapations are afterall as well discussing the intricacies of adapating something, those tags would suffice there, too.

So I would **propose the retirement of the [adaptation-differences](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adaptation-differences) tag and its confusing usage in favour of the already existing adaptation tags** altogether.

Comment: I think that the tag can be made valuable with the assistance of a wiki guidance and fixing the current usage. I'll bet that there are actually several questions that *should* have it that do not.

Comment: Also, I've created "play-adaptation" because we had at least two questions about play/musical adaptations that were using this tag and didn't have an appropriate xxx-adaptation tag yet.

Comment: @Catija Hmm, also possible. But I fail to see how the general adapation tags don't actually cover that, especially since it's not like those questions would make a huge subset of all the adaptation questions (let alone being flooded by adapation questions in general).

Comment: @Catija Well, for that we also had the general `adapation` tag, whose existence I agree is a little sub-optimal, though.

Comment: The value of any of them is questionable... they are inherently meta tags... not that we need to get into that argument again... we can talk about it TSR, though if you like.

Comment: But sure, it's a possiblity to retain it. But whatever happens, the specific question talked about here can't keep it.

Comment: So you completely change the meaning of the tag...

Comment: I've removed it from all of the inappropriate questions other than the one being discussed here.

Comment: @cde No, that was *always* the meaning, it just wasn't documented anywhere, which caused the confusion that led to this question. If it meant comparing an adapation to its source material, it would be redundant to the other adapation tags altogether and we could merge it into them.

Comment: "always the meaning" "it seems it is rarely ever used for that purpose" Do you always contradict yourself?

Comment: @cde Not always, and there's no need to get snarky here. I realized that it was quite wrongly used resulting from the lack of documentation on it. Yes, we made a mistake refusing to properly document it and letting it get out of hand this much. But as said, if it meant what you imply, we can as well remove it altogether anyway.

Comment: Compound tags are usually a bad idea. They confuse people.

Comment: I would agree with removing the tag - it seems unnecessarily specific and the more general tags would be good enough.

Answer (score 4):

Because you're not asking about the difference *between* two different versions of a story adapted into a film, you're asking how the film differs from the primary medium - the video game.

This was explained in the rollback reasoning:

> Rollback to Revision 3 - You are not comparing two different adapations to each other, which is what this tag is for.

The tag you're using would be used for a question like "How is The Hulk portrayed differently between the Ang Lee version and the current MCU version?"

To help clarify this, I have [submitted an edit](https://movies.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/53911) to the tag wiki excerpt.

Comment: And you suggest that based on what, removing the tag from every question when all of them talk about differences from the original material? http://movies.stackexchange.com/posts/53265/revisions Or other questions using it in the same way? http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/64418/what-changes-were-made-in-princess-kaguya-from-the-original-tale-of-the-bamboo-c

Comment: Why do you think that we need three tags that all mean the same thing? "adaptation" or "comic adaptation" already imply that the question is about the adaptation... which is usually the differences between them. Just because the tag usage was poorly defined doesn't mean that it's "changing" it only means that we are doing a better job now of explaining it.

Comment: Is that  why you added book-adaptation to a question tagged adaptation? Or that you created the book-adaptation tag in the first place?

Comment: We all make errors from time to time. :) There's nothing wrong with that! As a note, I didn't create the book adaptation tag. I did create a tag for play adaptations... perhaps that's what you mean?